# Change svg polygon attributes via Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, svg, setattribute

I am trying to scale and translate svg polygon elements, depending on the browser window size.
Calculating how much I want to scale and translate is not the problem, but changing the polygons is for me.

I am hoping you can help...

I have broken the issue down so that I count the number of polygons (this is ok):

```
function countnumberofPolygons() {
    numberofPolygons = document.getElementsByTagName("polygon").length;
    return numberofPolygons;
}
```

and a function that creates a string for determining the transform="" attribute of the polygon - the transform attribute can be say - transform="translate(800,00) scale(1.2)"

```
function createsvgtransformattribute(){
    transformattribute = '"translate('+ translateAmount +',0) scale(' + scaleAmount + ')"';
}
```

but looping through them and setting their attributes doesn't seem to work. I've broken it all down and built it back up - but end up with this - which is wrong, probably in some simple way....

```
function changeattributes(numberofPolygons, transformattribute){
    for (var q=0;q< numberofPolygons;q++){
        document.getElementsByTagname("polygon")[q].setAttribute("transform", transformattribute);
    }
}
```

But even when inserting the value of the string transformattribute manually, it doesn't work. Can you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the html I used the document read Jquery function and onresize to call svgscale().
There are a few oddities in the script - like the left side nudge - but hopefully it should work for others.

I have converted images in image tags to a div that has the image as a background-image. The image maps are then pulled into svg. Then this script uses the transform attribute of the svg to scale and translate the polygons of the image map accordingly.

```
var winWidth;
var winHeight;

var MainImageHeight;
var MainImageWidth;

var HeightRatio;                
var imageWidth;

var leftoffset;
var ImgVsOriginal;

var offsetnudge;
var offsetnudgescaled;
var los;
var translateAmount;
var scaleAmount;

var numberofNodes;
var numberofPolygons;
var polygonArray;
var transformattribute;


function setVariables(){

                                //Browser window widths and heights
                winWidth = window.innerWidth;
                winHeight = window.innerHeight;

                                                //Widths and heights of the element with the MainImage id
                MainImageHeight =   document.getElementById('MainImage').offsetHeight;
                MainImageWidth =    document.getElementById('MainImage').offsetWidth;

                                                //Establishes the ratio between the height of the element and the background image it displays,
                                                //which has a height of 920px
                                                //The MainImage resizes the background image so the ratio is needed to scale the svg/imagemap
                HeightRatio = MainImageHeight/920;

                                                //This establishes the width of the background image as presented - the background image file is 1400px
                imageWidth = HeightRatio*1400;

                                                //The Background image is centered and covers the screen. So there is space either side of the background image
                                                //This space is worked out here, and halved to work out the left-hand side portion of the space
                leftoffset = (winWidth-imageWidth)/2;

                                                //The original imagemap was created based on an image displayed as 960px by 653px. This calculates the ratio between them.
                ImgVsOriginal = MainImageHeight/653;

                                                //The original image was based on images with a small border each side. This is a hard-adjustment for this.
                offsetnudge = 30;

                                                //Scales the offset for this border based on the background image size vs the original
                offsetnudgescaled = offsetnudge*ImgVsOriginal;

                                                //Creates an easy to type variable based on 
                //los = leftoffset + offsetnudgescaled;
                translateAmount = leftoffset + offsetnudge;
                scaleAmount = ImgVsOriginal;
                                                //Creates variable for idname
                 var idname;      
                }






function createsvgtransformattribute(){
                transformattribute = 'translate('+ translateAmount +',0) scale(' + scaleAmount + ')';
                return transformattribute;
}


function countchildNodes(){
                numberofNodes = document.getElementById("svgstuff").childNodes.length;

                }

function printnumberofnodes(){
                document.write('<span>Number of Nodes:' + numberofNodes + '</span>');
}

function countnumberofPolygons(){
                numberofPolygons = document.getElementsByTagName("polygon").length;
                return numberofPolygons;
                }

function getpolygonArray(){
                polygonArray = document.getElementsByTagName("polygon");
}

function printnumberofPolygons(){
                document.write('<span>Number of Polygons:' + numberofPolygons + '</span>');
}







function changeattributes(){
                document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML='changed';
        for(q=0; q<polygonArray.length; q++){
        //document.getElementsByTagName('polygon')[q].setAttribute("class", "blue");
        document.getElementsByTagName('polygon')[q].setAttribute("transform", transformattribute);
        }
}




function svgscale(){
                setVariables();
                getpolygonArray();
                createsvgtransformattribute(translateAmount, scaleAmount);
                changeattributes();
        }
```

Here are some example polygons for you:

```
<div id="MainImage">
    <svg onresize="svgscale()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    style="position:absolute;"
    width="2000" height="2000"
    pointer-events="visible">       
        <a xlink:href="1.htm" xlink:title="1">');   
            <polygon id="p1" class="" points="736,378 680,363 680,233 736,209 736,378" transform="" fill="" >
            </polygon>
        </a>
        <a xlink:href="2.htm" xlink:title="2">
            <polygon id="p2"class="area" points="839,161,742,204,739,513,831,587,839,161" transform="" fill="">

            </polygon>
        </a>
        <a xlink:href="3.htm" xlink:title="3">');   
            <polygon id="p3" class="area" points="521,286,521,296,557,297,555,287,521,286" transform="" fill="" >

            </polygon>
        </a>
        <a xlink:href="4.htm" xlink:title="4">');   
            <polygon id="p4" class="area" points="562,218,562,240,657,242,657,219,562,218" transform="" fill="" >

            </polygon>
        </a>
        <a xlink:href="5.htm" xlink:title="5">');   
            <polygon id="p5" class="area" points="952,273,909,275,905,276,902,347,858,344,846,351,845,356,855,361,845,542,849,546,849,572,846,573,845,575,841,652,954,652,952,273" transform="" fill="" >
            </polygon>
        </a>                    

    </svg>

</div>
```

I put some ids in the polygons in case I couldn't cycle through by TagName, but it works by obtaining the polygons by tagname and cycling through via a for loop. :-)
The css for the #MainImage div is basically:

```
#MainImage {background-image: url('pix/file.jpg'); background-size: auto 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set a transform attribute using setAttribute you don't put it in double quotes. So what you need is

```
transformattribute = 'translate('+ translateAmount +',0) scale(' + scaleAmount + ')';
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually tried this before, but sadly it doesn't work, so I assume that there is something else that I am doing wrong. Do I need to use the 'this' keyword here?

Comment: Hello, I got it eventually -- and you are right that it doesn't need double quotes. Here is my entire script....